# KendoUI add event after a component initialization

Tags: kendo-ui

How can I add a change event after initialization in a KendoUI autocomplete? I'm building in this way, but I don't know how to do this with the component already built.

```
<input id="autocomplete" />
<script>
$("#autocomplete").kendoAutoComplete({
  change: function(e) {
    var value = this.value();
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this link: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/autocomplete#events-change

```
<input id="autocomplete" />
<script>
function autocomplete_change(e) {
  var value = this.value();
  // Use the value of the widget
}
$("#autocomplete").kendoAutoComplete();
var autocomplete = $("#autocomplete").data("kendoAutoComplete");
autocomplete.bind("change", autocomplete_change);
</script>
```